# mcs : Metadata file not found

Tags: c#, visual-studio, nuget

I'm trying to run a csharp program on the ubuntu commandline using

```sh
mcs hello.cs
```

It works but I want to use the nuget i download with nuget CLI with the following :

```cs
using Mailjet.Client;
using Mailjet.Client.Resources;
using System;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
namespace Mailjet.ConsoleApplication {
 class Program {
  static void Main(string[] args) {
   RunAsync().Wait();
  }
..........
```

Then I get the error :

```sh
hello.cs(1,15): error CS0234: The type or namespace name `Client' does not exist in the namespace `Mailjet'. Are you missing an assembly reference?

hello.cs(2,15): error CS0234: The type or namespace name `Client' does not exist in the namespace `Mailjet'. Are you missing an assembly reference?                        
hello.cs(4,7): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `Newtonsoft' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
```

So i refered to a SO answer and tried this

```sh
mcs /reference:Mailjet.Api.1.2.2 /reference:Newtonsoft.Json.9.0.1 hello.cs
```

Now I get a Different Error

```sh
error CS0006: Metadata file `Mailjet.Api.1.2.2' could not be found                                      
error CS0006: Metadata file `Newtonsoft.Json.9.0.1' could not be found
```

Ive tried other methods like

```sh
mcs hello.cs -r:Mailjet.Api.1.2.2 -r:Newtonsoft.Json.9.0.1
```

but no difference made

This is my directory structure

```
.
├── Mailjet.Api.1.2.2
│   ├── Mailjet.Api.1.2.2.nupkg
│   └── lib
│       ├── net45
│       │   └── Mailjet.Client.dll
│       └── netstandard1.1
│           └── Mailjet.Client.dll
├── Newtonsoft.Json.9.0.1
│   ├── Newtonsoft.Json.9.0.1.nupkg
│   ├── lib
│   │   ├── net20
│   │   │   ├── Newtonsoft.Json.dll
│   │   │   └── Newtonsoft.Json.xml
│   │   ├── net35
│   │   │   ├── Newtonsoft.Json.dll
│   │   │   └── Newtonsoft.Json.xml
│   │   ├── net40
│   │   │   ├── Newtonsoft.Json.dll
│   │   │   └── Newtonsoft.Json.xml
│   │   ├── net45
│   │   │   ├── Newtonsoft.Json.dll
│   │   │   └── Newtonsoft.Json.xml
│   │   ├── netstandard1.0
│   │   │   ├── Newtonsoft.Json.dll
│   │   │   └── Newtonsoft.Json.xml
│   │   ├── portable-net40+sl5+wp80+win8+wpa81
│   │   │   ├── Newtonsoft.Json.dll
│   │   │   └── Newtonsoft.Json.xml
│   │   └── portable-net45+wp80+win8+wpa81
│   │       ├── Newtonsoft.Json.dll
│   │       └── Newtonsoft.Json.xml
│   └── tools
│       └── install.ps1
├── hello.cs
├── hello.exe
└── tree.txt

14 directories, 22 files
```

Pls help me. I dont want to use visual studio IDE

Comment: Do you particularly need to use `mcs` directly rather than the .NET Core SDK? The latter would make all of this rather simpler. But if you *do* want to specify the reference, you should specify the complete path to the DLL you want to refer to.

Comment: @JonSkeet Can you provide an example of full path

Comment: Given what you've got, something like `Mailjet.Api.1.2.2/lib/netstandard1.1/Mailjet.Client.dll`

Comment: @JonSkeet that's wrong syntax : using Mailjet.Api.1.2.2/lib/netstandard1.1/Mailjet.Client.dll is obiously not working. I get Syntax errors. I suppose  I didnt understand your point

Comment: No, not for the `using` directive - for the command line, where you're trying to specify the reference. When you specify other assemblies to use, you need to specify the path to the file.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use command in this format:

```
mcs  /reference:Mailjet.Client.dll /reference:Newtonsoft.Json.dll hello.cs
```

For this format, we need to make sure the `Mailjet.Client.dll` and `Newtonsoft.Json.dll` are in same folder where `hello.cs` exists.

(Copy the two assemblies in `netstandard1.x` folder to the folder where `hello.cs` file exists)

**In addition:** You can also specify the references with full path like:

```
mcs  /reference:path/Mailjet.Client.dll /reference:path/Newtonsoft.Json.dll hello.cs
```

Comment: Can simply serve the full path of the assemblies instead of copying them around.

Comment: Of course it also supports the full path, will add it:) Thanks for the hint!

Comment: Thanks for anwsering

Comment: You're welcome:) If this issue won't block you any more(when this issue is resolved), please feel free to let me know, then we can  archive this thread!